# Python regex replace all patterns except when it is next to a repeated pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python and I have a multi-line string that looks like:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
The quick quick brown fox jumps over the quick lazy dog. This a very very very very long line.
This line has other text?
The quick quick brown fox jumps over the quick lazy dog.
```

I would like to replace all occurrences of `quick` with `slow` but with one exception. When `quick` is proceeded by `quick` then only the first `quick` is converted by the second, neighboring `quick` is left unchanged.

So, the output should look like this:

```
The slow brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
The slow quick brown fox jumps over the slow lazy dog. This a very very very very long line.
This line has other text?
The slow quick brown fox jumps over the slow lazy dog.
```

I can do this using multiple passes where I first convert everything to `slow` and then convert the edge case during my second pass. But I'm hoping that there is a more elegant or obvious one-pass solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) using a negative lookbehind to replace `quick` when not preceded by the same substring:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(?<!quick\s)quick', 'slow', s)
```

Using the shared examples:

```
s1 = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. '
s2 = 'The quick quick brown fox jumps over the quick lazy dog. This a very very very very long line.'

re.sub(r'(?<!quick\s)quick', 'slow', s1)
# 'The slow brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. '

re.sub(r'(?<!quick\s)quick', 'slow', s2)
# 'The slow quick brown fox jumps over the slow lazy dog. This a very very very very long line.'
```

---

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<!quick\s)quick`

  - Negative Lookbehind `(?<!quick\s)`

    - `quick` matches the characters quick literally (case sensitive)
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - quick matches the characters quick literally (case sensitive)

Comment: thanks in advanced if you can explain `(?<!quick\s)quick` this syntax.

Comment: Added some more details on the pattern. You can find more detailed information at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html @KushanGunasekera

Comment: @KushanGunasekera: if you are interested in concept of *zero-length assertion* I suggest this article https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html as starting point

Comment: thank you so much @Daweo, I'll check it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant for regex engines that do not support look-aheads:

```
quick(( quick)*)
```

replaced by

```
slow\1
```

Comment: It's  brilliant! And we can use \s*, too, which is not possible in python look-behind. re.sub(r'quick((\s*quick)*)',r'slow\1',txt)

Comment: Good point! (Just clarifying: variable length look-aheads are possible in Python. Only look-behind is limited in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

You could harness *grouping* for this task, following way:

```
import re
txt1 = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
txt2 = 'The quick quick brown fox jumps over the quick lazy dog.'
out1 = re.sub(r'(quick)((\squick)*)',r'lazy\2',txt1)
out2 = re.sub(r'(quick)((\squick)*)',r'lazy\2',txt2)
print(out1) # The lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
print(out2) # The lazy quick brown fox jumps over the lazy lazy dog.
```

Idea is pretty simple: 1st group for first `quick` and 2nd group for rest quicks. Then replace it with `lazy` and content of 2nd group.